# Why filter function returns empty array?

Tags: javascript

Filter function

```
function filter(array,test) {
    let passed = [];
    for (let element of array){
        if (test(element)) {
            passed.push(element);
        }
    }
    return passed;
}
```

Array

```
a = [{name: 'John', sport : 'football'},
    {name: 'Sergio', sport : 'football'},
    {name: 'John', sport : 'basketball'},
    {name: 'Jova', sport : 'football'},
    {name: 'Jon', sport : 'basketball'},
    {name: 'Lemmi', sport : 'football'},
    {name: 'Josh', sport : 'football'},
]
```

When I run my code

```
console.log(filter(a, i => i.name['Lemmi']));
```

I got

```
[]
```

How to edit the line to get

```
sport: 'football'
```

output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i => i.name['Lemmi']` returns the property `'Lemmi'` in `i.name`, which is not an object, but a string, so it returns `undefined` for all of your entries.

Try with:

`console.log(filter(a, i => i.name === 'Lemmi'));`

Answer (score 2):

Javascript already has an `.filter()` method

```js
let a = [{name: 'John', sport : 'football'},
    {name: 'Sergio', sport : 'football'},
    {name: 'John', sport : 'basketball'},
    {name: 'Jova', sport : 'football'},
    {name: 'Jon', sport : 'basketball'},
    {name: 'Lemmi', sport : 'football'},
    {name: 'Josh', sport : 'football'},
]

let result = a.filter(el => el.name === "Lemmi").map(el => ({sport: el.sport}));

console.log(result);
```

In your code you need to check it with `el.name === "Lemmi"` and to get only the property `sport` you could additionally map over it.

```js
let a = [{name: 'John', sport : 'football'},
      {name: 'Sergio', sport : 'football'},
      {name: 'John', sport : 'basketball'},
      {name: 'Jova', sport : 'football'},
      {name: 'Jon', sport : 'basketball'},
      {name: 'Lemmi', sport : 'football'},
      {name: 'Josh', sport : 'football'},
]

function filter(array,test) {
    let passed = [];
    for (let element of array){
        if (test(element)) {
            passed.push(element);
        }
    }
    return passed;
}
 console.log(filter(a, i => i.name === 'Lemmi').map(el => ({sport: el.sport})));
```

Comment: I want only the second line.

Comment: @RichardRublev how about now?

Comment: Question: _"Why filter function returns empty array?"_, Answer: _"Use this"_ - This really explains it... :/

Answer (score 1):

Your `filter` function receives two parameters - an input array and a test function.

There are two different issues in your question:

1. You pass an [arrow function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp) as `filter` function, but in incorrect way. What you pass implicitly, is:

   ```
   function (i) {
       return i.name['Lemmi'];
   }
   ```

   while what you want to do is:

   ```
   function (i) {
       return i.name === 'Lemmi';
   }
   ```

   So, what you should pass is `i => i.name === 'Lemmi'`.
2. If you want to collect a specific property of filtered items, you should pass a format function:

   ```
   function filter(array,test,format) {
         :
         :
       if (test(element)) {
           passed.push(format(element));
      }
   }
   ```

   and then call with:

   ```
   filter(a, i => i.name === 'Lemmi', i => i['sport'])
   ```